# open webservice from android device which is hosted in laptop

Tags: android

I have a webservice which is hosted in IIS in windows 8 laptop. I have created an android app which accesses the remote web service and displays the list in fragment which is working fine in android emulator. Now challenge for me is to access the same service from android app when i install it on my android device.

Is network sharing required for this? how to make it if required..

I m using following link in emulator to access webservice

http ://192.168.xxx.xxx/WebService/MainService.svc/GetDataList/0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your laptop to the internet and the get IP from there.

Make sure your actual device is connected to the internet as well.

Put the IP you got in the first step as the server address.

Comment: I got the ip from ipconfig and put the same as server address in android browser.. its not working..

Comment: I am not getting any error. Can you tell me simple method to access localhost IIS Page in android browser??

Comment: I havent worked with IIS in particular. This is how I connect to my webservices in general.